# Why does the current node not change to its left child even though it has one

Tags: java, recursion, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I debugged it and noticed that when the current node is 10, it goes through the second as it should, then it's called again, but the current node is still 10 instead of being 2

Instructions:

Implement a member method inRangeValues which returns a Java Array List with all the key value pairs from the tree that have a key that is greater than or equal to a key key1,
and less than a second key key2 (this is called a range query).

The two keys are passed as parameters. Recall the private class MapEntry from theBinarySearchTree that implements the interface KeyValuePair.

The elements in the array list must be ordered in pre-order.

```
        inRangeValues(20, 51)
        T1.put(50, 50);
        T1.put(10, 10);
        T1.put(56, 56);
        T1.put(2, 2);
        T1.put(23, 23);
        T1.put(70, 70);
        T1.put(0, 0);
        T1.put(61, 61);
        Expected value: [50 23]
```

```
   this is how the tree looks: 
                   50
           10______||______56 
      2____||___23          |____70             
 0____|                    61____|
```

```
                public ArrayList<KeyValuePair<K, V>> inRangeValues(K key1, K key2) {
                    ArrayList<KeyValuePair<K, V>> L = new ArrayList<KeyValuePair<K, V>>();
                    recIRV(L, key1, key2, root);
                    return L;           
                }
                public void recIRV(ArrayList<KeyValuePair<K, V>> L, K key1, K key2, BinaryTreeNode<MapEntry<K,V>> R) {
                    if(keyComparator.compare(R.getValue().getKey(), key1) >= 0 && keyComparator.compare(R.getValue().getKey(), key2) < 0) {
                        L.add(R.getValue());
                    }
                    if(R.getLeftChild() != null) {
                        recIRV(L, key1, key2, root.getLeftChild());
                    }
                    if(R.getRightChild() != null) { 
                        recIRV(L, key1, key2, root.getRightChild());
                    }
                    else {
                        return;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: i just found out my issue, i was calling the child nodes with root instead of using R...

Comment: i spent hours debugging and analyzing both this and another excercise, and BOTH had the same issue, i passed both after realizing, appreciate it tho.

Comment: Good, so there is no more question then?

Comment: Nope, appreciate the intention tho, i still have 2 more excercises left and i may need help on one of them, maybe ill post it.

Comment: Just realise that (1) this algorithm doesn't meet the requirement *"must be ordered in pre-order"*, and (2) isn't efficient, as it visits *all* nodes of the tree.

Comment: i agree with (2) but about (1), why? it does imo, pre-order = root,left,right afaik

Answer (score 0):

The recursive call inside the last 2 if statements should have:

R.getLeftChild()    and R.getRightChild()

instead of:

root.getLeftChild() and root.getRightChild()